# Excel - if first cell of row equals a value/string and then count if cells in row equal a value/string

Tags: excel, match, countif

I'm stumped with an Excel issue. I have tried variations of COUNTIFs and INDEX MATCH and can't get it to work.

I have a spreadsheet with labels for each row vertically in the first column. what I want to do is, if the first cell of a row equals a specific value/string, then I want to count all occurrences of a different value/string in that row.

I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Edit:

If I have a table like so

```
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Blue      |        Dave      |        Dave      |                  |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        Red      |                  |        Dave      |                  |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Yellow     |        Dave      |        Dave      |       Andy       |
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|       Green     |                  |                  |       Andy       | 
|-----------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

My question is, how can I can count all occurrences of "Dave" in the row where the first column equals "Yellow"?

Comment: Can you be more concrete and specify some sample values, and the desired outcome given these values? Also provide the exact formula you tried with and in which cell(s) the output should go.

Comment: By different, do you mean different than the value in the first cell? Do you want to count unique values? Or all different values? I.e. if the first row is "A", "B", "C", "B", "A", should the result be 2 ("B" and "C") or 3 ("B". "C", "B")?

Comment: @trincot - Edited to be a little clearer

Comment: @V.K. - They don't have to be unique. It's just that the cell values are likely to be different to the values in the first column.

Comment: And another question: do you want to have this formula copied in each row and then calculate this for each row 'Yellow' or do you want to have one single formula for the whole table, which means you also need to locate the row which contains 'Yellow'? And in the latter case, what if there are more 'Yellow's in the first column? Shall it count only with the first one?

Comment: Or if there are multiple rows starting with 'Yellow', do you want to count the total number of 'Daves' in all of them?

Comment: Hi all. Sorry if I hadn't been clear. The first column will be unique. I have a another sheet that has all of the values that would be in the first column. On that sheet I want to be able to count all of the occurrences of a specific value/string, e.g. "Dave". In the example above, there should never be multiple occurrences of the same value in the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your other sheet (say Sheet2) has "Yellow" in A1, try:-

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$D$4,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4,0),0),"Dave")
```

in Sheet2!B1

[image]