# EXCEL - count names per week - count row values X for all rows with value Y in the first cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have this table:

[image]

Note that the same name will never appear more than once in each row.

Now... given the name X and the week Y, I want to count all occurrences using these criteria (X and Y).

For example: how many times "John" appears in WEEK 1? Answer: 3.

Actually, I'd like to create another table like that:

[image]

And fill it with the COUNTS of each person by week.

I've tried combinations of functions like COUNTIF, MATCH, INDEX and VLOOKUP, without success. I couldn't find a way to deal with ranges and arrays as input for criteria.

I've also tried this solution: [Excel - if first cell of row equals a value/string and then count if cells in row equal a value/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743634/excel-if-first-cell-of-row-equals-a-value-string-and-then-count-if-cells-in-ro)
But it only returns the first occurrence of each week.

Comment: =SUM(N(FILTER(C2:E31,B2:B31=1)="John")) for John in week 1

Comment: Instead of functions and formulae in Excel, have you considered using Excel's Power Query to import this range and UnPivot the range using your criteria?

Comment: @user11222393 you should post it as an answer, considering my initial objective was exactly that (given name X and week Y, count all occurrences). I'd flag it as the solution. It worked perfectly for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP proposed to post formula as an answer. To get count for week *1* in column `B` and name "*John*" in columns `C:E`:

```
=SUM(N(FILTER(C2:E31,B2:B31=1)="John"))
```

Comment: In my case, this solution is preferred because it gives me more flexibility while creating the second table, allowing me to define each cell the way I want. 

Although P.b's answer (using MMULT or MAKEARRAY) also works by creating the full table in a more automatic way, using only one formula in a single cell.

Answer (score 1):

Using office 365 you could use either:

```
=MMULT(N(TOROW(C2:E31)=G3:G5),N("Week"&INDEX(B2:B31,SEQUENCE(ROWS(C2:E31)*COLUMNS(C2:E31),,1,1/3))=H2:L2))
```

or

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(G3:G5),COLUMNS(H2:L2),LAMBDA(x,y,SUMPRODUCT((C2:E31=INDEX(G3:G5,x,))*("Week"&B2:B31=INDEX(H2:L2,,y)))))
```

[image]